# What is a yeast cake?

Tags: substitutions, yeast

Kids and I are reading a book written in the 50's, and there's a recipe in the book that uses one "yeast cake"?  What is a suitable replacement in dry yeast?

The rest of the recipe (this is from memory) uses 1C Milk, 1 Egg, 1C flour and several other smaller amounts of flavoring/ingredients.

Comment: A whole yeast cake today is typically 2oz, which is a lot of yeast. How much of what does the recipe make?

Comment: Here's a handy [converter](http://www.traditionaloven.com/conversions_of_measures/yeast_converter.html) once we figure out how much fresh yeast they mean by a "cake".

Comment: It looks like .6 oz cakes are standard too. That would be 2 tsp of instant dry yeast, which makes more sense.

Comment: @Jolenealaska : Bob's Red Mill shows [one cake being the equivalent to one packet of dried](http://blog.bobsredmill.com/featured-articles/active-dry-yeast-vs-compressed-yeast/) : "One (1/4-ounce) yeast packet of dry yeast OR 1 cake fresh, compressed yeast EQUALS 2- 1/4 teaspoons dry yeast (active dry or instant active dry)"

Comment: @Joe That makes perfect sense and it meshes (pretty closely) with what I was able to find. I bet that's what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bob's Red Mill website](http://blog.bobsredmill.com/featured-articles/active-dry-yeast-vs-compressed-yeast/) states that one cake is the equivalent to one packet of dried yeast (0.25oz or 2.25 tsp):

> One (1/4-ounce) yeast packet of dry yeast OR 1 cake fresh, compressed yeast EQUALS 2- 1/4 teaspoons dry yeast (active dry or instant active dry)