# active dry yeast vs instant yeast

Tags: bread, yeast

This [Mediterranean breakfast bun recipe](http://en.passionforbaking.com/blog/2012/10/29/mediterranean-style-breakfast-bun/) calls for active dry yeast which is dissolved in tepid milk. What should I change if I use instant yeast instead?

> Mediterranean Style Breakfast Buns (Yield: 12)
>
> 1 3/4 oz. (50 g) fresh yeast
>      1 cup + 1 tablespoon (250 ml) tepid milk
>   1/4 cup (60 g) regular sugar
>   1/4 cup (50 ml) sunflower oil
>   3 1/2 oz. (100 g) feta cheese , crumbled
>   1 medium boiled potato,
>   grated   2 1/2 cup (315 g) all-purpose flour
>   1 teaspoon salt

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9355/67  (note that although they asked about rapid rise, one of the answers talks about the differences between instance and rapid rise, as well)

Comment: oops ...and as YosemiteMark noticed, it called for fresh (aka cake yeast) ... see  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4119/67 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/44957/67

Comment: I know this is an old question, but: 50g fresh yeast for 315g flour is *a lot*. Half the amount and a bit longer rising time will improve the taste significantly. As it's written, the yeast flavor will be very prominent, even with the feta and such. And with less yeast, the buns will stay fresh longer.

Comment: I have found that instant yeast rises more and faster than dry yeast. Just my experience speaking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active dry yeast and instant yeast are pretty much interchangeable in recipes (although instant may have somewhat more activity that an equal amount of active dry)

However, your recipe calls for **fresh** yeast.  The general rule of thumb (referenced [here](http://makebread.com.au/fresh-yeast-conversion/)) is to divide the amount of fresh yeast by 3 to convert to active dry or instant yeast.  Your recipe would therefore call for a little more than 1/2 oz of dry.  That would be about 2 packets (or 4 1/2 teaspoons) of active dry or instant.

Comment: What happens to the water that we dissolve active in if I want to substitute instant for it?

Comment: The total liquid in a recipe should stay the same in either case.