# What are the conversion rates between yeasts: cake yeast(compressed yeast), dry active, instant, and yeast flakes.

Tags: yeast

What are the conversion rates between yeasts: cake yeast(compressed yeast), dry active, instant, and yeast flakes.

Preferably in grams please.

Comment: What are "yeast flakes"?

Comment: Danny, would you see [this q/a](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46074/active-dry-yeast-vs-instant-yeast?rq=1) as close enough to be a duplicate? Rule of thumb: fresh : dry (instant) = 3:1, active : instant = 1:1 to 1.4:1, depending on the sources.

Comment: Don't forget water content. Especially if you happen to use yeast slurry from your beer :)